# Как обновлять базу посоветуйте простой способ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

Хочу управлять **Active Directory** через сайт. Добавлять удалять и изменять пользователей. 
На сервере будет запущенна консоль, которая будет в бесконечном цикле опрашивать **AD** на изменения, по параметру **ObjectGuid** это своего рода уникального не изменяемого номера для каждого пользователя. 
Если что-то меняется то есть появляется новый пользователь, то консоль пишет его в Базу **MySQL**. Так же нужно предусмотреть действия над объектами изменение ну к примеру изменение фамилии или какого-нибудь другого параметра, так же консоль сопоставляет данные из **AD** и **MySQL** и вносит изменение в последнее.

Я попытался изобразить, как я представляю его работу на картинке ниже.

[image: Процесс работы]

Правильно ли я понимаю процесс работы? И что Вы по-советуйте?

Answer (score 1):

Как бывший админ могу сказать пару слов:

Прямой доступ к АД не самая лучшая идея, тем более на внесение изменений, т.к. это огромная дыра в безопасности.

Хороший путь - написать сервис, который будет отвечать за авторизацию, добавление, удаление, редактирование и предоставление списков пользователей (это могут быть и отдельные сервисы) и инкапсулировать все внутреннюю кухню работы с AD. С сайта обращаться к этому сервису когда понадобится. Это будет проще чем синхронизировать информацию в AD и MySQL и гораздо безопаснее.

Не претендую на единственно правильное решение, возможно есть варианты проще.